# CkEditor textarea return always null in controller POST method? ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ckeditor

I have configured `CKEditor` in my asp.net mvc project. Its showing fine but it return always `null` value in controller `HttpPost` method.

Controller:

```
 [ValidateInput(false)]
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
   
    public ActionResult CreateActor([Bind(Include = "ActorId,Name,AlternateName,BirthDate,Height,ImageUrl,Executive")] Actor actor)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Actors.Add(actor);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("LoadActors");
        }

        return View(actor);
    }
```

View:

```
 @model MA2231A5.Data.Actor

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create Actor";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/38.1.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>

 }
<style>
.ck-editor__editable_inline {
    min-height: 125px;
  }
 </style>
<h2>Create Actor</h2>

  @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

  <div class="form-horizontal">
       <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Biography, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Biography, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "ckeditor" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Biography, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <script type="text/javascript">ClassicEditor.CKEDITOR('Biography');</script>


        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create"  class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
   }
        <script>
ClassicEditor
    .create(document.querySelector("#Biography"))
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });


 </script>

 @section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

   }
```